# glassfish gem fails to start on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, glassfish, jruby

I'm trying to run a rails 3 app on a windows server using jruby and glassfish gem. I can run the app fine using "rails s". Here's my probelm:

C:\webapp\mcs>jruby -S glassfish

Starting GlassFish server at: 0.0.0.0:3000 in development environment...
Writing log messages to: C:/webapp/mcs/log/development.log.
Press Ctrl+C to stop.

```
java/util/ServiceLoader.java:207:in `fail': java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Pla
tformMain: Provider com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASEmbedded could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalArgume
ntException: URI is not hierarchical (NativeException)
        from java/util/ServiceLoader.java:164:in `access$100'
        from java/util/ServiceLoader.java:353:in `next'
        from java/util/ServiceLoader.java:421:in `next'
        from org/glassfish/api/embedded/Server.java:644:in `getMain'
        from org/glassfish/api/embedded/Server.java:263:in `<init>'
        from org/glassfish/api/embedded/Server.java:61:in `<init>'
        from org/glassfish/api/embedded/Server.java:158:in `build'
        from org/glassfish/api/embedded/Server.java:140:in `build'
        from org/glassfish/scripting/gem/GlassFishMain.java:122:in `startGlassFishEmbedded'
        from org/glassfish/scripting/gem/GlassFishMain.java:298:in `start'
        from c:/jruby-1.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.2-universal-java/lib/server.rb:146:in `start'
        from c:/jruby-1.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.2-universal-java/lib/server.rb:146:in `start'
        from C:/jruby-1.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.2-universal-java/bin/glassfish:55
        from C:/jruby-1.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.2-universal-java/bin/glassfish:19:in `load'
        from c:/jruby-1.5.6/bin/glassfish:19
```

I'm sure it's a simple environment setup thing, any suggestions? Much appreciated.

Comment: You might get some help here   http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-embedded-web-start-so-close-0

Comment: Yep, been there, but didn't really get anywhere with it - no solution provided. I've also asked gem publisher the same question in the hope that he will go "oh yeah, you've got to..."!

Comment: It seems to be a dependency issue. What I got out of that thread is that the glassfish.jar is required.

Comment: Okay, I see where you're going with that, I'll have a dig around. I have installed glassfish server on the box, but perhaps I need to update the classpath or something like that. It's been a while since I did java stuff - got involved in ruby and never really looked back.

Comment: Try the latest glassfish gem release? Install with `jruby -S gem install glassfish --pre`. We haven't released 1.0.3 final quite yet.

Comment: Thanks - similar, but different: http://pastie.org/1363089

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by simply backing out to jruby-1.5.5. I intend to do a blog post on how I got this all running, because it was a bit of a nightmare, but it does appear to be holding together at the moment. my setup is:

windows server 2003 R2, rails 3.0.3, jruby 1.5.5, glassfish gem 1.0.2

NOTE: I think this fix solves the problem in jruby-1.5.6 but not yet in the compiled distro, so I just decided to back out:
https://github.com/jruby/jruby/commit/621bce3056f71cc9cd0e1b8aa59cecae1fc15e45

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to talk about the 1.0.3.beta.1 code. As mentioned, the error is similar,but I suspect they are different manifestations of the same issue.

Glassfish gem relies on akuma library ( http://java.net/projects/akuma/ ) to go into the background. If you tried to load this it with JRuby, you get the error messages like these:

```
NameError: cannot link Java class com.sun.akuma.CLibrary, probable missing dependency: Unable to load library 'c': The specified module could not be found.

    from org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:1054:in `for_name'
    from org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:34:in `get_proxy_class'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:46:in `java_import'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3.beta.1-universal-java/lib/server.rb:56:in `(class Server)'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3.beta.1-universal-java/lib/server.rb:53:in `(class GlassFish)'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3.beta.1-universal-java/lib/server.rb:52:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1041:in `require'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3.beta.1-universal-java/lib/server.rb:31:in `require'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3.beta.1-universal-java/lib/glassfish.rb:2:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1041:in `require'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glassfish-1.0.3.beta.1-universal-java/lib/glassfish.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):2:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1091:in `eval'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1416:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1194:in `rbCatch'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1194:in `rbCatch'
    from c:/Users/asari/Documents/Development/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
```

You see that JNA cannot load the "C" library. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Thanks, anyone want to tackle this one?

Comment: Akuma works only on Unix-like operating systems. It does not work on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue running a rails 3.0.3 app with each of these setups:

**These don't work:**

windows, jruby-1.6.0.RC1, glassfish-1.0.3.beta.1-universal-java

windows, jruby-1.6.0.RC1, glassfish-1.0.3-universal-java

windows, jruby-1.6.0.RC1, glassfish-1.0.2-universal-java

windows, jruby-1.5.6, glassfish-1.0.3.beta.1-universal-java

windows, jruby-1.5.6, glassfish-1.0.2-universal-java

windows, jruby-1.5.3, glassfish-1.0.3.beta.1-universal-java

**This setup worked tho:**

windows, jruby-1.5.3, glassfish-1.0.2-universal-java

jjnevis says it works on jruby-1.5.5 and glassfish 1.0.2 as well so not quite sure if it's a bug introduced between jruby 1.5.5 and 1.5.6 or a bug introduced in the glassfish gem between 1.0.2 and 1.0.3. But hopefully that helps someone else pin point it down.. I'm headed to bed sorry.. Might have another look at it tomorrow